# htaccess, third level domain, wrong redirect to robots.txt

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

it is continuation to this question [htaccess 301 redirect from third level domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20466394/htaccess-301-redirect-from-third-level-domain/)

Everything is working allright, but a new issue appeared.

```
start.example.com/robots.txt => another.example.com/robots.txt
```

but it should redirect other way

```
start.example.com/robots.txt => www.example.com/robots.txt
```

start.example.com and www.example.com use the same folder /home/site1/public_html/

and another.example.com uses another folder /home/site2/public_html/

How can it be, any ideas?

P.S.

All three websites share the same IP

Comment: If you mean a *redirect* (`[R]`-flag) (not a *rewrite*), then you can simply redirect to `http://another.example.com/robots.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file under `home/site1/public_html/`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^start\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?start=1&$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^start\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Have I got you right that after putting this code, start.example.com/robots.txt will be redirected to www.example.com/robots.txt ? then why is there another.example mentioned?

Comment: Probably I got confused by first line, let me try to understand it one more time.

Comment: may be I should add to .htaccess file under home/site2/public_html/ some redirection? if it see that folder somehow.

Comment: If DocumentRoot for `start.example` is `/home/site1/public_html/` then it belongs to `/home/site1/public_html/.htaccess`